# SQLAlchemy query result time out

Tags: python, mysql, sql, extjs, sqlalchemy

I'm developing a Extjs 4 application, I execute a query with parameters sent from the GUI (textboxes, comboboxes values, etc.). 
The query is built with SQLAlchemy. And I'm using MySQL database on localhost.

The queries I execute are meant to return big data. My problem is when I execute the query directly on HeidiSQL it executes in 0.6 seconds, but with Extjs (on chrome) it produces a time out and no results are shown.

This is the query. When I execute it, it should return 300.000 rows.

```
SELECT  /*ALL OF THE COLUMNS OF MY TWO TABLES, GENERATED DYNAMICALLY WITH SQLAlchemy*/
FROM bl, `CR`
WHERE `CR`.`Category` IN ('Failure') AND bl.severity_logged IN ('4_minor') AND bl.product_logged = 'x' AND bl.`productRelease_logged` IN ('0.1', '6.2', '6.4', '6.7');
```

What could be the problem?
Is it a browser cache problem?

**EDIT** : This is my Python script w/ SQLAlchemy.

```
engine = create_engine(
             "mysql://:@localhost/test",
             isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED"
        )
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
cr =  meta.tables['cr']
bl = meta.tables['bl']

session = create_session(bind=engine)
...#I create filters based on the GUI values
test_query = session.query(metric_table_object,cr).filter(all_filters) #I then create the query
result_dict = [u.__dict__ for u in test_query.all()] #I store the query result into a dict
print result_dict
```

Comment: Are you sure you are closing all previous sessions? using session.close(), also if you can print your code it will be much easier.

Comment: I don't use session.close(), where should I put it? Directly after declaring `session = create_session(bind=engine)`?

Comment: I have updated my question with the Python code.

Comment: When you finish with the session, i don't know how many sessions are opened since there is no code, but it's good practice to close all sessions (it's a must actually) it's like leaving an open port...

Comment: session.close() didn't change anything...

Comment: there's a big difference between time it takes for a query to *start* returning results and for it to *return all rows*.  300K rows is *a* *lot*.   It's probably taking a long time and might even be thrashing memory, take a look at RAM usage and all that.

Comment: yeah 300K ORM objects in an array, that is an enormous amount of python overhead both in terms of CPU and memory.   I'd find a different way to achieve what you want rather than loading 300K rows into memory, are you trying to generate a report file of some kind that you need all those rows at once ?

Comment: Well what I need to do is, get the 300 000 query rows results, store them in a list of dicts (Python) then calculate some metrics on the results. Maybe I don't need to store the query results into memory in order to later do the calculations on them? What do you suggest, i'm a newbie in Python so your help would be great!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having similar issues with ExtJS 5 -> Flask-SQLAlchemy timing out for complex queries.

Comment: Just figured it out. The Query runs more than 30 seconds directly via the API. ExtJS has a default of 30 seconds timeout for Ajax. The timeout parameter can be set in the Ext.Ajax.Request, which I set as `timeout: 60000`... worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

As [zzzeek comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356338/sqlalchemy-query-result-time-out#comment28696120_19356338), loading 300,000 result objects may be using too much memory. Perhaps you can work with your data in chunks using a tactic like the [Windowed Range Query](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/WindowedRangeQuery)? [This post on the SqlAlchemy mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg05200.html) also has some useful details on slicing your results into chunks.